# Adding Qt to existing GNU C++ program

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, g++

I have a current C++ program built using GNU make. It is reasonably large - about a dozen .cpp files and a similar number of headers.

It all runs off the command line and currently just outputs to cout and cerr.

I want to add Qt interface elements to it - what is the best way to do this?

(I have built some Qt stuff in the past (not for a few years) though I am rusty - the C++ code I have now works and I don't want to change that, just fix the way it outputs information to the end user.)

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking, as well as what you've tried (if anything). Ignoring your current makefile, how would you go about creating a makefile for a new qt-based program? Just do that, and then add in your existing sources (along with Qt-appropriate changes for the UI).

Comment: I am hoping for some practical pointers. "Just do that" isn't one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site that accepts broad / open-ended questions, but yours seems to be exactly that. You need to be able to get yourself started before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify whether you're interested in Qt Widgets or Qt Quick, so I'll assume widgets.

Fire up [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/index.html), and [create a new Qt Widgets project](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html). Open [designer mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-to-know.html) by double clicking on the `.ui` file that was created and start creating the interface that you want. If you just want somewhere to start integrating your logic, dump your existing code into `mainwindow.cpp` (or whatever you called it) and refactor it as you learn more about Qt.

For example, one of your buttons might cause a [slot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) to be invoked, and you could then do all of your stuff in that slot.

There are also a lot of non-gui-related utility classes like [QCommandLineParser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html) that may help you out.